# Magento override enterprise banner

Tags: magento

Is it possible if I could override Enterprise Banner Package? 
The class that I want to override is in
\app\code\core\Enterprise\Banner\Block\Widget\Banner.php

Here's part of my config.xml:

```
<blocks>                    
   <Mycomp_Banners>
      <class>Mycomp_Banners_Block</class>
   </Mycomp_Banners>
   <widget>
      <rewrite>
        <banners>Mycomp_Banners_Block_Widget_Banners</banners>
      </rewrite>
    </widget>   
 </blocks>
```

My file is in: \app\code\local\Mycomp\Banners\Block\Widget\Banners.php

```
class Mycomp_Banners_Block_Widget_Banners extends Enterprise_Banner_Block_Widget_Banner {   
    // ... 
}
```

I tried this, but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

In order to rewrite a block (but could also apply to Helpers and Models, controllers having different behaviour), you have to mimic the way they are defined in their own module's `config.xml`

So in the `config.xml` of `Enterprise_Banner`, the blocks are defined this way :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Enterprise_Banner>
            <version>1.11.0.0</version>
        </Enterprise_Banner>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <!-- nodes we don't care about -->
        <blocks>
            <enterprise_banner>
                <class>Enterprise_Banner_Block</class>
            </enterprise_banner>
        </blocks>
        <!-- more nodes we don't care about -->
    </global>
    <!-- still more nodes we don't care about -->
</config>
```

So your should mimic this definition of the block but where Magento is actually defining where the **class** is, you actually have to define what you want to rewrite and where it is going to be.

So your `config.xml` should looks like that :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycomp_Banners>
            <version>0.0.0.1</version>
        </Mycomp_Banners>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <enterprise_banner>
                <rewrite>
                    <widget_banner>Mycomp_Banners_Block_Widget_Banners</widget_banner>
                <rewrite>
            </enterprise_banner>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks, I made it works. The only thing that I need to modify is instead <widgent_banners> it should be only <widget_banner> ( with no "s" ) because after the rewrite tag, it should point to original block. In this case there is no "s".